# What does psuedo-polynomial algorithm for subset sum problem mean?

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

Help me out here - just trying to better understand what 'psuedo-polynomial' means...

If the input to an NP-Complete problem is 100 items(ie n=100), and the 'target' is the actual value '100'(t=100): Does a psuedo-polynomial algorithm take n*t (ie.. 100*100) steps to complete?

If so it seems to me that a psuedo-polynomial algorithm is *much* faster than exponential algorithm.

C

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a simpler example.  Let's consider an algorithm $A$ that takes an input $n$ and then counts up to $n$.  How long does this take?  Obviously, it takes time $O(n)$.  Is $n$ a polynomial?  Yes, but it is not a polynomial in *the length of the input to $A$*.  The length of the numeral $n$ is only $\log n$, so time it takes to $A$ to count to $n$ is exponential *in the size of the input*.

The problem here is that numerals are very short compared with the numbers they represent.  A big number like ten billion can be represented as an 11-digit numeral, and even a vast number like $10^{100}$ can be represented easily as a 101-digit numeral. Even though there are less than $10^{100}$ particles in the universe, you can write $10^{100}$ on a single paper in a minute.

A pseudo-polynomial algorithm is one whose inputs are numbers, and which runs in time that is a polynomial function of the largest of these numbers.  But an algorithm that is polynomial in the size of the largest number is *exponential* in the length of the input, because numerals are so very compact.

You can solve subset-sum in time $nt$.  But the length of the input in this case is only $\log n +\log t$, so this running time $nt$ is not a polynomial function of the length of the input.

The practical result of this is that for reasonable problem sizes, involving reasonable-size numbers, the straightforward dynamic programming algorithm solves subset-sum fast enough.  But this is useless for solving NP-complete problems more generally. For suppose you have an instance of some problem like SAT with say 100 clauses. The reduction to subset-sum will result in a subset-sum instance with $n$ and $t$ about as long as the original SAT instance—in fact some polynomial function of this length. In the best case that polynomial function will be linear, so the $n$ and $t$ you get will have something like $100$ digits each.  But that means that $n$ and $t$ themselves will be something like $10^{100}$.  And even though $n$ in such a case is only $100$ digits long, there is not enough time in the universe to solve subset-sum in time $nt$ when $n$ or $t$ is on the order of $10^{100}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the pseudo-polynomial algorithm takes $O(nt)$ steps. However, this may not be faster than the exponential algorithm. Suppose $t\approx 2^n$? Then the algorithm takes $O(n2^n)$ steps, which is the same as the exponential algorithm, and it takes way more space.